# Obtain column names efficiently which have values in R

Tags: r, select

I have a table `(Table1)` and I need to obtain the column names of first 10 columns which have values (NOT the column names which have "All") and the column names of the rest (11 to end)

This is to use inside a function so the column names having "All" varies. But, need to find the column names of first 10 columns which DOES NOT have "All". I guess is there a way check whether a column have values or "All" string.?

Is there an efficient way of doing this in R using `colnames` function

Thanks.

```
Table1:

St abb  crp  crp_N plan pln_ab prac prac_N fun scd    prm  lib   count
1  DL   All  All   All  All    All  All    All 09/30  5230 120   2
.
.

Output: 

St, abb, scd
```

Comment: Could you post the dput of the example, i.e. `dput(Table1)` which will give the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
names(Table1)[1:10][unlist(Table1[, 1:10, with = FALSE][, 
         lapply(.SD, function(x) all(x != "All"))])]
```

-

Comment: well..this is to use inside a function so the column names having "All" varies. But, need to find the column names of first 10 columns which DOES NOT have "All". I guess is there a way check whether a column have values or "All" string.?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the original post but have revised the post.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason head(colnames(Table1)[Table1 != "All"], 10) shows all the column names of first 10 columns. But, ONLY needs the column names which do not have "All".

Comment: still the same. Showing all the colnames of first 10 columns.

Comment: My first 10 columns are characters. Will this be the problem I am not getting the desired output?

Comment: Mine is a data table. str(). Is there a way to convert this to data table way of doing it?

Comment: In my Table1 I have 2033 rows whereas I have shown one row of data. will that be a problem?